# how to replace particular field in file

Tags: perl

In a file :

```
"name": "test","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:121212 ,
"name": "test1","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:12123212 ,
"name": "test2","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:121223212 ,
"name": "test3","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:121223212 ,
"name": "test4","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:121223212 ,
```

I want replace all the no into *

```
"name": "test","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:***** ,
"name": "test1","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:***** ,
"name": "test2","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:***** ,
"name": "test3","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:***** ,
"name": "test4","Address": "UK" "currency": "£" no:***** ,
```

and want append back into file

Comment: Is this related to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619863/how-do-i-replace-the-middle-of-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one-liner should do it:

```
 perl -i.bak -pe 's/(?<=no:)\d+/****/' filename
```

Comment: This creates an extra temp file, which Tree said in a comment that he didn't want to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -pe 's/no:\d+/no:*****/' < input_file > output_file
```

Comment: This will replace the `no:` along with digits

Answer (score 1):

```
cat input | perl -lne 's/^(.+)no:(\d+)(.*)/print"$1no:","*" x length($2),"$3"/e' > output
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be tempted to use [File::Map](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File::Map) to change the file in place. If I do that, however, I have to replace the digits one-for-one since this won't move the other characters in the file:

```
use File::Map qw(map_file);

map_file my $map, 'test.txt', '+<';
$map =~ s/(?<=no:)(\d+)(?=\s*,$)/ '*' x length $1 /meg;
```